# Convert gps coordinate to EPSG:32640

Tags: c#, gps, maps, gis

I need to convert gps coordinates to EPSG:32640 in c#. Are there some formulas for this?

Thanx

Comment: couldn't find any conxerting measurements, only that converting is called 'transformation'. there are transformation details in this link https://sdi.abudhabi.ae/Sites/SDI/Content/EN/PDF/GISDay/gis-day-2009-presentation-wrm-2-common-coordinate-system,property%3Dpdf.pdf which may help you but can't help you with any code sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just FYI, that EPSG you give is WGS84 (UTM 40N).  Most GPS data is in WGS84 unless otherwise specified, so you don't need to transform the datum (which mathemtically extremely complicated), you just need to repoject.  Is there a reason you need a formula for this, or could you use an existing library?  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184469/know-of-any-c-sharp-spatial-data-libraries) discusses C# spatial libraries, most of which can do this for you.

As for the formula, take a look at this page which discusses converting latitude/longitude to UMT coordinates: http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/usefuldata/utmformulas.htm